# Calculate number of events per last 24 hours with Redis

Tags: redis

Seems, it's common task, but I haven't found solution.

I need to calculate number of user's events (for example, how many comments he left) per last 24 hours. Older data is not interesting for me, so information about comments added month ago should be removed from Redis.

Now I see only one solution. We can make keys that includes ID of user and hour of day, increment it value. Then we will get 24 values and calculate their sum. Each key has 24 hours expiration.

For example,

1. Event at Jun 22, 13:27 -> creating key _22_13 = 1
2. Event at Jun 22, 13:40 -> incrementing key _22_13 = 2
3. Event at Jun 22, 18:45 -> creating key _22_18 = 1
4. Event at Jun 23, 16:00 -> creating key _23_16 = 1
5. Getting sum of event at Jun 23, 16:02 -> sum of keys _22_17 - _22_23, _23_00 - _23_16: in our keys it's only _22_18 and _23_16, result is 2. Keys _22_13 and _22_13 are expired.

This method is not accurate (it calculates count of events per 24+0..1 hour) and not so universal (what key will I choose if I need number of events per last 768 minutes or 2.5 month?).

Do you have better solution with Redis data types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model seems fine. Of course, it's not universal, but it's what you have to sacrifice in order to be performant.

I suggest you keep doing this. If you will need another timespan for reporting (768 minutes), you can always get this from mysql where your comments are stored (you do this, right?). This will be slower, but at least the query will be served.

If you need faster response or higher precision, you can store counters in redis with minute resolution (one counter per minute).

Comment: Thanks! If we will take minute precision, we need multiget of 1440 keys for each request. Don't like it. I think, that hour precision is OK for me if there is no other possibility to increase it.

Comment: You could have 5-minute intervals, for example. It's a balance between precision and resource consumption.

Answer (score -3):

You can use redis EXPIRE query after each key creation.

```
SET comment "Hello, world"
EXPIRE comment 1000 // in seconds
PEXPIRE comment 1000 // in milliseconds
```

Details [here](http://redis.io/commands/expire).

Comment: How does this answer his question?

Comment: @Sergio If we select all keys it pull all keys per last 24 hours (if we specify 24 hours expiration)

Comment: Sure, I implied EXPIRE when wrote "Keys _22_13 and _22_13 are expired."

Comment: If you will set expiration, outdated keys will be deleted, but how we will retrieve data? Write an example with keys names.

Comment: Now, I understand your question. You need *dynamic* parameter for obtaining keys in date range like sql `WHERE date > somedate`?

Comment: Yes, @mishadoff, it's our goal.

Comment: In all fairness to this answer: it is your question that's ambiguous, not this answer. "I need to calculate number of user's events per last 24 hours". This can be very well done by running a counter that you expire after 24 hours. All you need to do is add everything up and you're done.